# Koa send status 404 every time is

Tags: node.js, koa, koa-router, koa2

```
export async function getPlaces(ctx, next) {
    const { error, data } = await PlaceModel.getPlaces(ctx.query);
    console.log(error, data);
    if (error) {
        return ctx.throw(422, error);
    }
    ctx.body = data;
}
```

Koa everytime sends 404 status and empty body, what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: 404 usually mean Koa cannot find a route matching the url, are you sure the above function called ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, console.log works

Comment: Did you try `try/catch` around the await call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In seems that, `await` does not really "wait" and therefore returns too early (this results in a 404 error).

One reason for that could be that your `PlaceModel.getPlaces(ctx.query)` does not returns a promise. So it continues without waiting on results from `getPlaces`.

Answer (score 5):

I also had this issue, and resolved it by adding :

`ctx.status = 200;`

directly below

`ctx.body = data;`

Comment: This was it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to wire up your function with the router. Here's a little example how it works:

```
import * as Koa from "koa";
import * as Router from "koa-router";

let app = new Koa();
let router = new Router();

async function ping(ctx) {
  ctx.body = "pong";
  ctx.status = 200;
}

router.get("/ping", ping);

app.use(router.routes());
app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have middleware that is being triggered before this async function, but that middleware isn't async.

1. If you have any non-async middleware that gets called before this function, convert it to async.
2. Instead of calling `next();` in the async middleware, call `await next();` even if it is the last line of the middleware function.

Answer (score 0):

in my case while using koa router i had forgotten to add

```
app.use(router.routes())
```

just above

```
app.listen(port)
```